# Problem with the focus in Eclipse SWT when clicking on Actions in ActionsBars

Tags: eclipse, swt, rcp, e4

In a Eclipse RCP/RAP project we are using several views with IActionBars and Actions contributed using E4 (xml Actions/Commands defined in the plugin.xml file).

Let's say that we have two views (IWorkbenchPart) opened (A and B) with both an ActionBar with Actions. If the View A is focused and we click directly on an Action of View B, the focus is not being changed to View B. The code of the Handler for the action looks like this:

```
public class DefineFilterHandler extends AbstractHandler
{
    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException
    {
        IWorkbenchPart part = HandlerUtil.getActivePart(event);

        if (part == null || !(part instanceof ViewB))
        {
            return null;
        }

        ViewB view = (ViewB) part;

        // open filter dialog
        view.showSetFilterDialog();

        return null;
    }

}
```

The dialog is only shown when we click on ViewB first to set the focus. In other cases in which for example we are showing two instances of ViewB, the Dialog or whatever action, is being executed on ViewB1 instead of in ViewB2 (just because ViewB1 is the focused one).

I have been trying to detect the click on the IActionBars or the actions inside, to set the focus on the correct View before the Handler is called, but with no success.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps use `IWorkbenchPage.findView` to find the view by id rather than expecting it to be the active part.

Comment: This solution works when the Views are different (View A and View B) but not when there are different instances of the same view (View B1 and View B2)

Comment: Views can have secondary ids to distinguish mutiple instances of the same id. See IWorkbenchPage.findViewReference

Comment: This is a good solution indeed but I do not know how to pass the secondary Id to the Handler. I have tried this approach http://blog.eclipse-tips.com/2008/12/commands-part-3-parameters-for-commands.html but I can list the views ID but not the secondary Id. I am going to try to do it programatically in the View itself, looping through the contributed items of the action bar, but I do not like this solution very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this problem by setting the focus to the View containing the action bar with the commnands:

```
IActionBars bars = getViewSite().getActionBars();
    
    IContributionItem [] items = bars.getToolBarManager().getItems();        
    for(IContributionItem item : items)
    {
        if(item instanceof HandledContributionItem)
        {
            HandledContributionItem handledContributionItem = (HandledContributionItem)item;                
            ParameterizedCommand c = handledContributionItem.getModel().getWbCommand();
            c.getCommand().removeExecutionListener(this);
            c.getCommand().addExecutionListener(this);
        }
    }
```

The code above is placed in the "doCreatePartControl" method of the View. This code sets the Execution Listener. So the View now implements org.eclipse.core.commands.IExecutionListener

Implementing the method "preExecute" like this:

```
@Override
public void preExecute(String commandId, ExecutionEvent event) 
{
    String secondaryId = ActivityView.this.getViewSite().getSecondaryId();
    IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
    for(IWorkbenchPage page : workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getPages())
    {
        IViewReference viewReference = page.findViewReference(ActivityView.this.getViewID(), secondaryId);
        if(viewReference != null)
        {
            try 
            {
                page.showView(ActivityView.this.getViewID(), secondaryId, IWorkbenchPage.VIEW_ACTIVATE);
            } 
            catch (PartInitException e) 
            {
                ActivityDisplayPlugin.getPlugin().logError("Problem getting Activity View", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We can set the focus on the correct View before calling the handler. This solves the problem.